# Установка состояния загрузки кнопки геопозиции

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться - есть задача, сделать кнопку определения геолокации как на [боевых картах яндекса](https://yandex.ru/maps/213/moscow/?ll=37.622504%2C55.753215&z=10): при нажатии на кнопку, пока происходит определение геолокации должен появляться лоадер.

В [песочнице](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/) видно, что это не стандартное поведение кнопки (если кликнуть на неё, она просто становится серой, лоадера не появляется).

Нашёл в доке описание класса [GeolocationControl](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.GeolocationControl.html#control.GeolocationControl__param-parameters.state), через который создаётся кнопка, там вижу только   возможность передать изображение кнопки для её обычного состояния, через поле data.image.

Как мне повторить поведение кнопки на карте с лоадером?

Answer (score 0):

Если честно, не получается на Яндекс.Картах разглядеть лоадер, слишком быстро всё происходит.

Вы можете задать иконку кнопки через [parameters.data.image](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.GeolocationControl.html#control.GeolocationControl__param-parameters.data.image). Сначала вам нужно подписаться на [событие click](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.GeolocationControl.html#control.GeolocationControl__events-summary) по кнопке геолокации, затем методом [control.options.set()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/controls/edit.html#controls__options-example4) меняете иконку кнопки. И затем после [locationchange](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.GeolocationControl.html#event_detail__event-locationchange) возвращаете прежнюю иконку.